# Importing scipy.misc.pilutil in python using Komodo and Anaconda?

Tags: python, scipy, komodo, anaconda

Anaconda installs with Scipy, and in the scipy-0.12.0-np17py27_0.json file, this is listed:

```
"Lib/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", 
"Lib/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.pyc",
```

In the library folder, this is listed:

```
Lib/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py
```

But, running this:

```
import scipy.misc.pilutil as smp
```

Gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pilutil'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `scipy.misc.__init__` deletes the `pilutil` module - [relevant code line](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/misc/__init__.py#L60) - so you cannot import it directly. But all functions from the `pilutil` module are, before that, added to the `misc` module, and you can use them from there:

```
In [1]: from scipy import misc
In [2]: misc.fromimage
Out[2]: <function scipy.misc.pilutil.fromimage>
In [3]: misc.bytescale
Out[3]: <function scipy.misc.pilutil.bytescale>
```